# Postgres constraint name need to be unique across single table or entire schema?

Tags: postgresql, constraints, exclude-constraint

I'm trying to understand why some Postgres constraints can be named the same within different tables, and some don't

Here a simple example:

```
drop table if exists public.table_1;
drop table if exists public.table_2;

CREATE TABLE public.table_1 (
    id serial NOT NULL,
    date_start date NOT NULL,
    date_end date NULL
);

CREATE TABLE public.table_2 (
    id serial NOT NULL,
    date_start date NOT NULL,
    date_end date NULL
);


alter table public.table_1 add constraint my_constraint_1 check (date_start > now());
alter table public.table_2 add constraint my_constraint_1 check (date_start > now());


alter table public.table_1 add constraint my_constraint_2 EXCLUDE USING gist (daterange(date_start, coalesce(date_end, 'infinity'),  '[]') WITH &&);
alter table public.table_2 add constraint my_constraint_2 EXCLUDE USING gist (daterange(date_start, coalesce(date_end, 'infinity'),  '[]') WITH &&);
```

As you can see I can use the same name `my_constraint_1` with different tables
[image]

Why the name `my_constraint_1` can be used as the same in different tables, while `my_constraint_2` must be unique otherwise I get the error  `Errore SQL [42P07]: ERROR: relation "my_constraint_2" already exists`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why the name my_constraint_1 can be used as the same in different tables, while my_constraint_2 must be unique

Constraint 2 has underlying index with the same name, while constraint 1 is simple check contraint on table level.

> [EXCLUDE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/sql-createtable.html#SQL-CREATETABLE-EXCLUDE)
> Exclusion constraints are implemented using an index, so each specified operator must be associated with an appropriate operator class (see Section 11.10) for the index access method index_method.

```
CREATE INDEX my_constraint_2 ON public.table_1 USING gist (daterange(date_start, COALESCE(date_end, 'infinity'::date), '[]'::text))
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=7154ff9792f41d96b3800a340caeb4ff)**

Comment: Is there a way to force the index name different while having the constraint with the same name?

Comment: @DevilingMaster Interesting question, I do not see syntax that allow to give other name(but also I am not saying it is impossible)

Comment: @DevilingMaster No, the index must always have the same name as the constraint.